# COUNT() not displaying correct result

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with my code.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts as wposts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as rs ON (rs.object_id = wposts.ID)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1 ON (wposts.ID = m1.post_id )
WHERE (wposts.post_type = 'product' AND wposts.post_status = 'publish')
AND ( m1.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND m1.meta_value = 'instock' )
```

Now the problem is, some of the items are duplicated that's why it displays wrong count.

https://www.screencast.com/t/cmOku8G3nAF

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can you confirm the count is 2?The left table only have two records?

Comment: Maybe the right table has duplicate value or null value in related key.

Comment: Yes, only have 2 records

Comment: Check whether wp_term_relationships has duplicate object_id or object_id has null value,so does wp_postmeta.post_id.

Comment: Remove `GROUP BY`, select all columns (`SELECT * FROM ..`) and investigate all 21 rows which are counted.

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results if you want someone to be able to help you

Comment: I updated my question... I also replaced the link image. Kindly see

Answer (score 0):

If you want just  a count of posts, remove the group by and select `count(distinct wposts.ID)`.